# Rails and accessing Facebook api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, koala

I'm looking at creating an app that can access certain data from business pages via the Facebook api. I have done some reading and have found that Omniauth-Facebook and Koala are the go to gems. But, all the articles/tutorials I have come across use these gems to access user data. Will these gems access other pages data such as businesses? If anyone had anymore information on this topic, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provide [business manager api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager-api) using this you can access your business pages.